# not able to style the outer div which has got two divs inside

Tags: css, html

I have got a div id event_container and two div classes inside that div id by the class name create_event_button and search. I want to have a specific background for the event container and then style the classes differently.

Below is the css styling of these elements :-

```
#event_container{

    background: red;
}

 #event_container .create_event_button {

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
        width: 150px;
        color: #1C1C1C;
        background: #A9D0F5;
        font-size: 150%;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 1em;
    }
#event_container .search {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    background: #A9D0F5;
    padding: 1.4em;

}
```

The inner div stylings are working all right but the #create_event is not giving me a proper background color.

I have been trying to hack around this one but have not got any success yet. It would be great if anyone could answer it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer div contains only two floats, which are allowed to slip out of the parent div, unless you apply some clearfix trick ( there are many solutions: http://www.google.com/search?q=clearfix ), or simply use `overflow:hidden;` on the parent div to always contain any inner floats:

http://jsfiddle.net/E4J3Q/

Comment: thanks dude it works :) will check out the clearfix trick as well

Answer (score 1):

the two inside divs are floated, so the outside div (#event_container) would not have a height.

you can append a `<div class="clear"></div>` and add a css rule like this: `.clear {clear:both;}`

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ym9K9/

Comment: thanks will check it out although the solution provided by biziclop is working for me